# Twitter API tweet stream filtered on hashtag NodeJS

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm trying to get a stream of tweets from the Twitter API containing a certain hashtag using
NodeJS.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Sampled-Stream/sampled_stream.js) as a template for my purposes. According to [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/quick-start) and [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule) I should be using be requesting the tweets using the header.

[**This is what I tried**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llaha.png) I know this is not the for the hashtags, but I can't get this to work either.

Comment: Please provide your code here as outside links are unrelaible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Filtered Stream (not the Sampled Stream) in order to target specific values or hashtags. Check [the Filtered Stream sample](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.js).

The rules values specify what you are listening for - these are sent to a separate endpoint, and are not specified in the header.

In the case of the sample code, this is setup here:

```
const rules = [
    { 'value': 'dog has:images -is:retweet', 'tag': 'dog pictures' }, 
    { 'value': 'cat has:images -grumpy', 'tag': 'cat pictures' },
  ];
```

This defines two rules, identified by two separate *tags* (these help you to determine which rule was matched when the result comes through). The rule itself is determined by the *value*. This is where you could place a hashtag.